# AttributeError in Django

Tags: python, django

I am trying to get the author object which is imported from another model in the views and display it as a form but when I run the code the code is showing **'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'author'** error.`

This is the views.py:

```
def post_views(request):
profile = Post.objects.get(author=request.author)
form = PostModelForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None, instance=profile)
confirm = False

if request.method == 'POST':
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        confirm = True

context = {
    'profile':profile,
    'form': form,
    'confirm': confirm,
}

return render(request, 'posts/main.html', context)
```

This is models.py

```
class Post(models.Model):
no_people = models.IntegerField()
no_days = models.IntegerField()
tour_date = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
Gender_types = (
    ('M', 'Male'),
    ('F', 'Female'),
    ('O', 'Others'),
)
Gender_prefer = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=Gender_types)
location = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
pic_location = models.ImageField(blank=True, upload_to="posts/")
updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
detail = models.TextField() 
liked = models.ManyToManyField(Yatru, blank=True, related_name= 'likes')
author = models.ForeignKey(Yatru, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name = 'posts')

def __str__(self):
    return str(self.location)

def no_likes(self):
    return self.liked.all().count()

class Meta:
    ordering = ('-created',)

LIKE_CHOICES = (
('Like', 'Like'),
('Unlike', 'Unlike'),
 )
```

This is the main.html

```
{% block body %}
<form action="" method="POST" class="ui form" enctype='multipart/form-data'>
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{form.as_p}}
 </div>
 </div>

 <button type='submit'>
  Update
  
 </button>
 </form>
 {%endblock%}
```

This is the Yatru model

```
class Yatru(models.Model):
first_name = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
last_name = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
bio = models.TextField(default="Say Something about yourself!", max_length=300)
Gender_types = (
    ('M', 'Male'),
    ('F', 'Female'),
    ('O', 'Others'),
)
Gender = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=Gender_types)
email = models.EmailField(max_length=200, blank=True)
country = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
avatar = models.ImageField(blank=False, upload_to="avatars/")
friends = models.ManyToManyField(User, blank=True, related_name="friends")
slug = models.SlugField(unique=True, blank=True)
updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

objects = models.Manager()

def get_friends(self):
    return self.friends.all()

def get_friends_no(self):
    return self.friends.all().count()

def get_posts_no(self):
    return self.friends.all().count()

def get_all_authors_posts(self):
    return self.posts.all().count()

def get_likes_given_no(self):
    likes = self.like_set.all()
    total_liked = 0
    for content in likes:
        if content.value == 'Like':
            total_liked += 1
    return total_liked

def get_likes_recieved_no(self):
    posts = self.like_set.all()
    total_liked = 0
    for content in posts:
            total_liked += content.likes.all().count()
    return total_liked




def __str__(self):
    return f"{self.user.username}-{self.created.strftime('%d-%m-%Y')}"

def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    ex = False
    if self.first_name and self.last_name:
        to_slug = slugify(str(self.first_name) + " " + str(self.last_name))
        ex = Yatru.objects.filter(slug=to_slug).exists()
        while ex:
                to_slug = slugify(to_slug + " " + str(code_generator()))
                ex = Yatru.objects.filter(slug=to_slug).exists()
    else:
        to_slug = str(self.user)
    self.slug = to_slug
    super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

I updated the code to:

```
def post_views(request):
profile = get_object_or_404(Post, author=request.user)
form = PostModelForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None, instance=profile)
confirm = False

if request.method == 'POST':
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        confirm = True

context = {
    'profile': profile,
    'form': form,
    'confirm': confirm,
}

return render(request, 'posts/main.html', context)
```

Now the code shows this error:
**Cannot query "User": Must be "Model" instance.**

Comment: Please include *code*, not *images of code*: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question

Comment: Add Yatru model as well

Answer (score 2):

The logged in user can be retrieved with `request.user`, not <s>`request.author`</s>. You thus obtain the object with:

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404
from posts.models import Post

@login_required
def post_views(request):
    profile = get_object_or_404(Post, author=request.user)
    # …
```

It is also quite strange that you query the `Post` model, and store that in a variable named `profile`. If these are `Post`s, then likely the same user can be an author for *multiple* `Post`s.

---

> **Note**: It is often better to use [**`get_object_or_404(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/#get-object-or-404),
> then to use [**`.get(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#get) directly. In case the object does not exists,
> for example because the user altered the URL themselves, the `get_object_or_404(…)` will result in returning a *HTTP 404 Not Found* response, whereas using
> `.get(…)` will result in a *HTTP 500 Server Error*.

---

> **Note**: You can limit views to a view to authenticated users with the
> [**`@login_required`** decorator [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/default/#the-login-required-decorator).

Comment: I am still a beginner in Django. Thanks for the advice!